# Access extended properties in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing an app for Windows 8.1 that has a feature that displays a horizontal series of images that are contained within a wrapper class that I have extended from a previous API that I wrote.

Basically the set up is as follows:

I have base class A that exists within an external library that I am referencing.

I then have class B inside of my current project that extends A but add a `WriteableBitmap` property:

```
public class B:A
{
    private WriteableBitmap imageBitmap;

    public WriteableBitmap ImageBitmap
    {
        get { return this.imageBitmap; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, imageBitmap)) return;
            this.imageBitmap = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }    
}
```

I am then trying to display the images using a `ItemsControl` in `Xaml` with its `ItemSource` bound to a "ImageList" which is a list of my wrapper class (which in the XAML file is apparently being linked only to class `A`).

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <Image Source = "{Binding **trying to bind to the ImageBitmap property**}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

As you can see above, when I am trying to bind the `Image`, the only properties I have access to are the ones originally declared in the base class `A`. If I try to cast the binding somehow to to the newer subclass `B` like this:

```
<Image Source = "{Binding (ex:B.ImageBitmap)}"/>
```

That throws errors saying its an invalid binding.

For reference, `ex` is the name I gave for the namespace where `B` exists in the project at he beginning of the `Xaml` file.

Basically I am trying to figure out the proper way to cast a binding to a particular type that you have declared inside of the current project that extends a class that exists in an outside library that you are also referencing.

Any ideas?

Edit: To provide more detail as to what I am trying to do exactly, let me explain a little more and try to trim down the unnecessary details.

I have an external assembly, we will call it `ExternalLib`. Inside `ExternalLib` are the following classes:

- Class `A` which you saw above, which has various properties already declared in the external library.
- Another wrapper class called `ImagePackage` which contains the following property(s):

  `List<A> ImageList;`

  `String PackageName;`

Then in my current project I have class `B` which extends `A` and adds an additional `WriteableBitmap` property.

This all comes together in my app where I am trying to use nested `ItemsControl` to display a vertical list of `ImagePackage`, showing its `PackageName` as the header. Inside each vertical list is then a horizontal list that displays each image inside that list (which is obtained from the `WriteableBitmap` declared in `B`). To imagine this, think if how Netflix is laid out (vertical and horizontal lists together).

To accomplish this, I have a global data context that I use and I have the following `Xaml`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ImageRoot" Height="861" Width="656" DataContext="{StaticResource GlobalDataContext}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainImageInfo.ImagePackages}" DisplayMemberPath="PackageName">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>    
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <Image Source = "{Binding ImageBitmap}"/>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Trying to declare the source of the `Image` as `ImageBitmap` causes Intellisense to throw a fit, but it still compiles and runs. The issue is that when the binding actually tries to update the entire app crashes (even though I have it set to break on exceptions) saying:

```
MyAppName has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
```

Finally, the actual warning that Intellisense is providing on that line is:

```
Cannot resolve property "ImageBitmap" in data context of type "ExternalLib.A"
```

Comment: ImageList should be an ObservableCollection<B>, and all you need to do is bind to the property `{Binding ImageBitmap}` Done.  Also, you can have a collection of type A and bind to properties defined in B.  Bindings are cool with that.

Comment: @Will All of my properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I as under the assumption that you could either use an ObservableCollection<B> OR make sure that your properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged. With that being said, I still don't know why the new property declared in B, ImageBitmap, is not visible (does not show up in intellisense either) when I try to bind to it.

Comment: Don't worry about intellisense in xaml, it can be wonky.  INPC has nothing to do with this issue (it has to do with updating the UI when the view model changes).  Use OC<B> or OC<A>, has nothing to do with your issue. I have no idea ***what*** your issue is, as there is something else going on here that isn't included in your question.  Here's a repro I typed up in under three minutes.  You can create a copy of it and compare it to what you're doing, possibly [edit] to highlight where it differs from your solution: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wMlLf.png

Comment: @Will I added more details to my original post after realizing it might help to have more info. Any thoughts?

Comment: Man, your issue is somewhere else.  Does it crash during debugging?  Doesn't VS throw up the exception dialog?  If so, click that "copy details to clipboard" link and paste it in your question.  Otherwise, you're going to have to subscribe to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx and https://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=appdomain.unhandledexception and log that exception somewhere.  If you're lucky, details are already in the event log. Go look.

Comment: @Will It turns out my issue was related to the line defining the DisplayMemberPath of the outer ItemsControl. If I add an image I suppose it doesn't know how to display that member AND display an image in the "same space." Now my issue is trying to get the inner itemscontrol to let me scroll horizontally (it is currently only scrolling vertically using the outer itemscontrol).

Comment: That's a different question. Try creating a prototype (like mine!) that does the minimum and illustrates your issue. You may solve your problem by doing so, and if not, can use it to create a new question.  As for this question, add an answer below with code/xaml that explains your solution (doesn't have to be long) and you'll be able to select it as correct and close out your question.  That's how we handle self-answers around here.